# From Milan to Alps

Tags: italy, hiking, trekking, alps, milan

I need to spent four days in Milan in September. But during this period I would like to make trekking in Alps. Would you advice several places in Alps for trekking not very far for Milan? What is the best way to reach these places - bus/car/train ?

Comment: Alps is kinda broad. Care to narrow it down?

Comment: I never did taking in alps. Any convenient place reachable from Milan would be nice.

Comment: Still too broad. https://www.google.com/maps/place/Milan,+Italy/@45.5582698,9.3519654,9.75z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x4786c1493f1275e7:0x3cffcd13c6740e8d!5m1!1e4  The mountain range north of Milan is Alps

Comment: I think you should look around, pick a place in the Alps and then ask the question on how to get there. Don't mean to be rude or anything, it's just that the Alps are pretty huge, and one can kinda reach them in all sorts of ways.